# How to create input text controller like in the iphone message app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to do a chat app like the iphone message app. I use a UITableView to show the messages and under it i want to put some input text controller and a send button. the problem is that if i use a UITextField for the input controller it does not wrap the words and it does not look like the iphone message app controller.
how can i get the look&fill of the original controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have an open source of project that you're trying to develop. I think this will help: [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/acanichat). Also on cocoacontrols.com you can find bunch of useful projects so try to look there before reinventing the wheel.

Best of luck

Comment: i think i did no? i press yes to "Was this post useful to you?"

Comment: maybe you don't have enough privileges to mark it as answer.. there should be a checkmark underneath this gray number with up/down arrows around it..

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Chat Input Sample](https://github.com/alekperov/ChatInputSample) code. It has all the functionality what you needed.